# inserting data into a new column of an already exsisting table

Tags: mysql, sql

I added a new column to an already existing table, I just need to get data into this new column...I assume I can use a variant of the insert command, yet I do not know how to specify the column name and then how to order the values going into the new column.

Comment: It seems that you need an `UPDATE`. Since you didn't specifie your table and wht should go into that column. it is hard to help you.

Comment: ALTER TABLE matches ADD sex enum('m','f') is the command i used to add the column..now how can I enter data into this new column?

Comment: It means that every registry is either male of female, is there anything else on the table that identifies that? Because if it wont' you will have to do it manually. Otherwise  I can provide you a answer.

Comment: nothing else on the table identifies entries as male or female...is there not a way to use a command such as  "insert into matches column sex values (m,f,f,m)?

Comment: There is but whitout knowing which registry is male or female you have to update registry by registry. Is that what you need?

Comment: Ok I will add a answer to you.

Comment: or if there is a way to add the new column and the data all at the same time that would work as well

Comment: to do that you will have the same problem you need to know who is male and who is female. Whitout knowing this is just random guess. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after some conversation through the comments lets go to an answer.

I suppose your table is something like `id, name, age, dateBirth, etc fields`. But whoever create this table forget to add the gender for the registries. As you said that the new column is an `sex enum('m', 'f')` you will have to update every registry on this table one by one. Like this:

```
 update matches set sex = 'm' where id = 1;
```

Pay attention that with this command I just updated the row on the table where the id=1 and Im assuming that id is your primary key. On the where caluse you have to put your primary key, otherwise you may update more then one column.

If your table has many registries there is a way that you can do it cuting down the heavy work (at least a little)

In order to update many rows at once you have to do an Update with a LIKE filter, you will set a filter that can identifie many womans at a time then many men at time as this:

```
 update matches set sex = 'f' where name like '%Jheniffer%'
```

Since Jheniffer is a female name most likely you will update every registry which has part of the name as Jheniffer like 'Jheniffer Smith'. So repeat this process for the common names until the work is done. For all womens then repeat for the men.

Hope it help you to understand

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `update` command, `insert` is for adding new rows.

```
update myTABLE set NewColumn = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Why INSERT here? You need to UPDATE data to column inserted.
Here is the list of steps

1. Alter the table then add column with constraint is NULLABLE.
2. Process the update the column added using UPDATE command.
3. If you want the column added is NOT nullable. Just re-alter the column and change it to NOT nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UPDATE command.

```
UPDATE my_table SET new_col='new_val'
```

if you need to set new column value just in few rows add WHERE clause

```
UPDATE my_table SET new_col='new_val' WHERE condition='true'
```