# adding values to newly added column in exsting table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 INSERT INTO Employees (empId,name,salary,Email_id,DOB)

VALUES
('1','stephen','30000','stephen@gmail.com','1999-02-16'),
('2','andew','40000','andew@gmail.com','1995-12-09'),
('3','dev','16000','dev@gmail.com','1992-08-16'),
('4','jackson','25000','jack@gmail.com','1992-08-16'),
('5','shayam','33000','shaym@gmail.com','1992-08-16'),
('6','abc','31000','abc@gmail.com','1992-08-16'),
('7','xyz','32500','xyz@gmail.com','1992-08-16'),
('8','San','22000','san123@gmail.com','1992-08-16'),
('9','Sonu','29000','hkyadav@gmail.com','1992-08-16');
```

> NOW i added one more column to this existing table.

```
        ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES
        ADD age varchar(10);
    
    
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (age)
    VALUES
    (
    ('21'),
    ('22'),
    ('32'),
    ('35'),
    ('45'),
    ('39'),
    ('28'),
    ('26'),
    ('36')
    );
```

**I'm getting Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Comment: Get rid of the opening and closing parentheses - although you're probably looking for an UPDATE

Comment: Incidentally, one wouldn't normally store derived data

Comment: do you want to insert new rows for age or want to update age column for the existing data ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inserting data into a new column of an already exsisting table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509615/inserting-data-into-a-new-column-of-an-already-exsisting-table)

Answer (score 1):

The above exception is thrown when the number of columns in the insert statement is lesser than the number of values in the query. Please check the column and try to insert the value manually for the first time then run the insert script.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (age)
VALUES
(21),
(22),
(32),
(35),
(45),
(39),
(28),
(26),
(36)
;
```

This either will add new rows with all but age column NULL or will fail if some column is declared NOT NULL and has no DEFAULT value.
Provided the goal is not to add new rows but to update existing ones you need an UPDATE statement, kind of

```
update EMPLOYEES e,
   (values   
    row (1, 21),
    row (2, 22),
    row (3, 32),
    row (4, 35),
    row (5, 45),
    row (6, 39),
    row (7, 28),
    row (8, 26),
    row (9, 36) 
   ) t(empId, age)
set e.age = t.age
where e.empId = t.empId;
```

Comment: if i use this code INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (age)
VALUES
(21),
(22),
(32),
(35),
(45),
(39),
(28),
(26),
(36); I'm getting  Field 'empId' doesn't have a default value

Comment: @Ashish,  qiute possible : "or will fail if some column is declared NOT NULL and has no DEFAULT value". Have you tried the second query?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of above mentioned answer which worked for me on MSSQL server. Using the word row mentioned in the above answers was throwing me error. This syntax worked for me.

```
UPDATE employees
SET age =
(
SELECT age
  FROM
   (values 
      (1, 21),
      (2, 22),
      (3, 32),
      (4, 35),
      (5, 45),
      (6, 39),
      (7, 28),
      (8, 26),
      (9, 36)
   )AS s(Empid,age)
     WHERE s.EmpID=employees.Empid
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update EMPLOYEES e,
   (values   
    row (1, 21),
    row (2, 22),
    row (3, 32),
    row (4, 35),
    row (5, 45),
    row (6, 39),
    row (7, 28),
    row (8, 26),
    row (9, 36) 
   ) t(empId, age)
set e.age = t.age
where e.empId = t.empId;
```

Comment: it will be used to add the data into added colume to the table.

Comment: Is this just a typo fix suggestion to [the previous answer that has the same SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68053688/4957508)?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?